# Ada Sorting Composite Array

Tags: sorting, ada

I'm pretty new at Ada, and I have a question. This [`Demo_Array_Sort`](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Sort_an_array_of_composite_structures#Ada) from [Rosetta Code](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) uses the function "<" to determine how to sort the array. It sorts it by the name in alphabetical order. I understand this part. Where my question comes in is this:

If the array `Data` had multiple entries with the same name and I wanted to sort the list by value *within* `Name`, how would I do that? I've tried messing around with redefining the "<" function to no avail. Please help!

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Text_IO;           use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Generic_Array_Sort;

procedure Demo_Array_Sort is

function "+" (S : String) return Unbounded_String renames To_Unbounded_String;

type A_Composite is
 record
         Name  : Unbounded_String;
         Value : Unbounded_String;
 end record;

function "<" (L, R : A_Composite) return Boolean is
 begin
 return L.Name < R.Name;
 end "<";

procedure Put_Line (C : A_Composite) is
 begin
      Put_Line (To_String (C.Name) & " " & To_String (C.Value));
 end Put_Line;

type An_Array is array (Natural range <>) of A_Composite;

procedure Sort is new Ada.Containers.Generic_Array_Sort (Natural, A_Composite, An_Array);

  Data : An_Array := (1 => (Name => +"Joe",    Value => +"5531"),
 2 => (Name => +"Adam",   Value => +"2341"),
 3 => (Name => +"Bernie", Value => +"122"),
 4 => (Name => +"Walter", Value => +"1234"),
 5 => (Name => +"David",  Value => +"19"));

begin
   Sort (Data);
 for I in Data'Range loop
      Put_Line (Data (I));
 end loop;
end Demo_Array_Sort;
```

Example Data:

```
 Data : An_Array := (1 => (Name => +"Joe",    Value => +"5531"),
 2 => (Name => +"Adam",   Value => +"2341"),
 3 => (Name => +"Bernie", Value => +"122"),
 4 => (Name => +"Walter", Value => +"1234"),
 5 => (Name => +"David",  Value => +"19")
 6 => (Name => +"David", Value => +"42")
 7 => (Name => +"David", Value => +"5"));
```

Would output:

```
Adam 2341   
Bernie 122   
David 5
David 19
David 42   
Joe 5531   
Walter 1234
```

Answer (score 4):

In outline,

1. Change the `Value` component of `A_Composite` to a scalar subtype for which `"<"` is already suitably [defined](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-5-2.html#p8); I've chosen [`Natural`](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-5-4.html#p12):

   ```
   type A_Composite is
      record
         Name  : Unbounded_String;
         Value : Natural;
      end record;
   ```
2. Now it's easy to write a `"<"` that handles `L.Name = R.Name`:

   ```
   function "<" (L, R : A_Composite) return Boolean is
   begin
      if L.Name < R.Name then return True;
      elsif L.Name = R.Name then return L.Value < R.Value;
      else return False;
      end if;
   end "<";
   ```
3. Update `Put_Line` accordingly:

   ```
   Put_Line (To_String (C.Name) & Natural'Image(C.Value));
   ```

Data:

```
Data : An_Array := (
   1 => (Name => +"Joe",    Value => 5531 ),
   2 => (Name => +"Adam",   Value => 2341),
   3 => (Name => +"Bernie", Value => 122),
   4 => (Name => +"Walter", Value => 1234),
   5 => (Name => +"David",  Value => 19),
   6 => (Name => +"David",  Value => 42),
   7 => (Name => +"David",  Value => 5));
```

Console:

```
Adam 2341
Bernie 122
David 5
David 19
David 42
Joe 5531
Walter 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is an example using the Vector container.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;

procedure Main is
   type Surname is (Smith, Jones, Chen, Chavez);
   type Name is (John, Francis, Leslie, Margaret, George, Walter);

   type Person is record
      First : Name;
      Last  : Surname;
   end record;

   function Less(P1: Person; P2 : Person) return boolean is
   begin
      if P1.Last < P2.Last then
         return true;
      elsif
        P1.Last = P2.Last then
         return P1.First < P2.First;
      else
         return false;
      end if;
   end Less;


   procedure Print(P : Person) is
   begin
      Put_Line(P.Last'Image & ", " & P.First'Image);
   end Print;

   package Person_Vector is new Ada.Containers.Vectors(Index_Type   => Natural,
                                                       Element_Type => Person);
   use Person_Vector;
   package Person_Sort is new Generic_Sorting(Less);
   use Person_Sort;

   V : Vector;
   Temp : Person;
begin

   for N in Name loop
      for S in Surname loop
         Temp.First := N;
         Temp.Last := S;
         V.Append(Temp);
      end loop;
   end loop;

   Put_Line("Unsorted list:");
   for P of V loop
      Print(P);
   end loop;
   New_Line;

   Sort(V);

   Put_Line("Sorted list:");

   for P of V loop
      Print(P);
   end loop;

end Main;
```

The output of this program is:

```
Unsorted list:
SMITH, JOHN
JONES, JOHN
CHEN, JOHN
CHAVEZ, JOHN
SMITH, FRANCIS
JONES, FRANCIS
CHEN, FRANCIS
CHAVEZ, FRANCIS
SMITH, LESLIE
JONES, LESLIE
CHEN, LESLIE
CHAVEZ, LESLIE
SMITH, MARGARET
JONES, MARGARET
CHEN, MARGARET
CHAVEZ, MARGARET
SMITH, GEORGE
JONES, GEORGE
CHEN, GEORGE
CHAVEZ, GEORGE
SMITH, WALTER
JONES, WALTER
CHEN, WALTER
CHAVEZ, WALTER

Sorted list:
SMITH, JOHN
SMITH, FRANCIS
SMITH, LESLIE
SMITH, MARGARET
SMITH, GEORGE
SMITH, WALTER
JONES, JOHN
JONES, FRANCIS
JONES, LESLIE
JONES, MARGARET
JONES, GEORGE
JONES, WALTER
CHEN, JOHN
CHEN, FRANCIS
CHEN, LESLIE
CHEN, MARGARET
CHEN, GEORGE
CHEN, WALTER
CHAVEZ, JOHN
CHAVEZ, FRANCIS
CHAVEZ, LESLIE
CHAVEZ, MARGARET
CHAVEZ, GEORGE
CHAVEZ, WALTER
```

Note that the fields are sorted in the order their enumerations are specified in the program.